# Making Headshot Image Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on making my site responsive and I’m running into an issue with my header image. The image is a headshot and is aligned to the right. On both mobile and tablet, the image gets cut off at the bottom and the right side. I would like to have the headshot be centered and appear on top of h1,h3, and p in my header( on mobile and tablet). Is there any way to accomplish this while keeping my image still aligned to the right(on desktop)? Thanks!

```
HTML
  <!-- Header -->
    <header class="masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <h1>voluptatem accusantium</h1>
          <h3 style="margin-top:-2%">UX Research & Design</h3>
                  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.  </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

CSS

header.masthead {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("../img/headshot.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: right 85px top 80px;
  background-size: 400px 481px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed widths often make responsive designs more difficult. Have you thought about making the width of your image a percentage instead of fixed pixels?

Alternatively, you could just add media queries at the important break points. Something like (but dependent on your specific needs and layout):

```
@media screen and (max-width 1024px) {
    header.masthead {
        background-size: 300px 400px;
    }
}
```